# Pass yes answer to CMD

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, wmic

I would like to pass `yes` to CMD, but I am already passing this command `product where name="AWP v4.6 SR12 64-bit" call uninstall` using `echo` and pipe `|`. After this command is passed, it will ask me question if I want to uninstall and I need to pass yes command.

```
echo product where name="program name" call uninstall |wmic
```

I have tried `/interactive:off` switch but it always waiting for response.

Is there anothere way to make this work without any interaction? I just want to uninstall program from computer silently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `wmic` interactive:

```
wmic product where name="program name" call uninstall
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! ... But is there way to prevent it from rebooting by it self?